# Freezing dice rolled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random, dice

I am creating a game along the lines of Yahtzee the dice rolling game. I have to give the user 5 dice rolled, and ask them a 5 digit number of which dice they'd like to re-roll. For example:

```
Your roll is:  5 1 5 5 1
Which dice should I roll again?: 234
Your new roll is: 5 7 2 4 1
```

The three middle numbers change because those are the dice rolled.
I have no idea how to do this efficiently. I could create 240 if statements, but that does not seem like the proper way of going about this.

This is my code thus far:

```
import random

def yahtzee():
    dice1 = random.randrange(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randrange(1,6)
    dice3 = random.randrange(1,6)
    dice4 = random.randrange(1,6)
    dice5 = random.randrange(1,6)
    print('Your roll is: ' + ' ' + str(dice1) + ' ' + str(dice2) + ' ' + str(dice3) + ' ' + str(dice4) + ' ' + str(dice5))
    reroll = input('Which dice should I roll again?: ')
```

Which gives me the result:

```
yahtzee()
Your roll is:  4 3 2 1 5
Which dice should I roll again?:
```

Not sure how to go about re-rolling the dice. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's much easier to manage results stored in a list:

```
def yahtzee():
    dice = [random.randrange(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]
    print('Your roll is: ', *dice)
    reroll = input('Which dice should I roll again?: ')
    for i in reroll:
        dice[int(i) - 1] = random.randrange(1, 6)
    print('Your roll is: ', *dice)
```

Example output:

```
Your roll is:  5 3 2 5 3
Which dice should I roll again?: 12
Your roll is:  1 2 2 5 3
```

Comment: ah awesome, thank you so much, figured my code was very inefficient, really appreciate it!